# how to apply AccountingForm to TableView without affecting the row/column labels?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using M 8.0.4.

I am use TableView in demo Manipulate[] to display final solution data, which is a matrix of numerical data.

TableView is very nice to use, since it comes with an automatic scroll bars to move down the rows and to the right over the columns, so that one can see the whole matrix, while keeping the overall display area fixed. (I have an image at the bottom)

The problem that I am not able to find a solution for, is that I need to format the matrix data, so that it looks nice. Otherwise, if the a data element is too large to fit in a cell, it will wrap around, making the TableView misaligned. I also need to adjust decimal point an such other formatting.

I can't apply NumberForm nor AccountForm to the data, and then apply TableView on the result, because TableView does not like to see those wrappers, it needs the numbers.

But if apply the AccountingForm to the TableView, then the numbers that represent the row numbers and column numbers, which are added by TableView automatically, get formatted as well. And I do not want those formatted as well. A row number should remain an integer, not floating point. I just want the data itself formatted.

I could not figure how to format the data from inside Table view. When I use FullForm to see how the data is kept inside TableView, I could not figure how to format it without breaking TableView.

I'll show the problem, then show what I tried.

```
(* make up some data, and make a TableView of it *)
data = {{-1234.8, 0.123}, {0.12345678, 0.1234}}
tbl = TableView[data, ItemSize -> {{3, {8}}}, DefaultBaseStyle -> 11, 
  Spacings -> {.2, .1}, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

Notice the row numbers and columns number (marked) are positive integers.

Now, I wanted to format the data itself, (the exact formatting options used below is just an example)

```
AccountingForm[tbl, {6, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}, 
 NumberPadding -> {"", ""}, SignPadding -> True]
```

But now the Table rows and columns are also formatted:

[image]

The FullForm of TableView is:

```
In[156]:= FullForm[tbl]
TableView[List[List[-1234.8`,0.123`],List[0.12345678`,0.1234`]],
          Rule[ItemSize,List[List[3,List[8]]]],
          Rule[DefaultBaseStyle,11],Rule[Spacings,List[0.2`,0.1`]],
          Rule[FrameStyle,GrayLevel[0.5`]]]
```

So the data in TableView can be pulled out using

```
In[166]:= tbl[[1]]
Out[166]= {{-1234.8,0.123},{0.12345678,0.1234}}
```

But when I change `tbl[[1]]`, using `ReplacePart[]`, with an `AccountingForm` version of the data, `TableView` no longer works:

```
formattedData = 
 AccountingForm[data, {6, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}, 
  NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}, SignPadding -> True];

In[245]:= tbl=ReplacePart[tbl,1->formatted]
Out[245]= TableView[{{-1234.8,+0.123},{+0.123,+0.123}},
          ItemSize->{{3,{8}}},DefaultBaseStyle->11,Spacings->{0.2,0.1},
          FrameStyle->GrayLevel[0.5]]
```

So, I broke TableView. Since it does not display any more.

**Question is: How to format numeric data that goes into TableView without affecting the row/column index values?**

Fyi, this is how the TableView looks inside one Manipulate demo I have. Notice the automatics scroll-bars. (In this one, I am not using `NumberForm` and its friends to do the formatting. But what I did is not very efficient, I'd rather use `NumberForm` if I can, hence my question)

[image]

thanks

**update 12/22/11 1:30 AM**

Here is a complete code example for Mike to follow up on his answer below

```
data = {{-1234.8, 0.123}, {0.12345678, 0.1234}};

newData = 
  Map[AccountingForm[#, {6, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}, 
     NumberPadding -> {"", ""}, SignPadding -> True] &, data, {2}];

tbl = TableView[newData, ItemSize -> {{3, {8}}}, Spacings -> {.2, .1},
   FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

Now how exactly do I use the Cell command for the above? (This is in Manipulate, not a notebook session, Manipulate runs all in one cell.  I can't make separate cells and such in this code. But for trying it, I can in a new notebook, but the actual code that will use this solution, has to run in a Manipulate with no Cells.

**Update 12/22/11 5 am**

I am noticing some not good performance of TableView. Consider this code

```
Remove["Global`*"];
ClearSystemCache[]
m1 = MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd];
N[m1/10^6]
n = 256;
data = Table[RandomReal[], {n}, {n}];
TableView[data, ContentSize -> {300, 300}]
m2 = MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd] - m1;
N[m2/10^6]
```

The data itself, assuming double for the reals, is about half MB only. ByteCount says
2 MB due to other bookkeeping data struct.

```
In[114]:= ByteCount[data]/10^6//N
Out[114]= 2.10948
```

But Front end seems to use much more RAM (for the whole TableView I mean not just the data), sometimes I get 20 MB and sometimes much more (got 100 MB at one time).  But if you try the above on your computer, you'll notice M is having hard time with this. I think it might be the rendering of the table part that causes M to take so much time.

I do not think 256 by 256 is such a large matrix. Even with 128 by 128, it was having hard time to render it on the screen. Once it is up, then it is fast and no problem using it.

It looks like TableView is not yet optimized well.  I think I will only use it to display small part of the solution Matrix as the performance is not good to use it in a demo to display the whole solution, it will make the demo look bad.

The problem is that my solution matrix can be large, and I wanted a away to display the data in limited amount of GUI space. TableView is all what I can find that comes with scrollbars build-in. Nothing else in the Manipulate controls has something like this to use, so I have to use TableView.

**Update 12/22/11 4 PM**

Thanks for the hint by Mike below, I am now looking at using Pane with Scollbars, and it is working better than TableView. (still little slow with large data, but not as bad as TableView)

Here is a code example of doing that:

```
n = 32;
data = Table[RandomReal[], {n}, {n}];
grid = Grid[data, Spacings -> {.4, .4}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All];
grid = Style[NumberForm[grid, {6, 5}], LineBreakWithin -> False];
pane = Pane[grid, ImageSize -> {200}, Scrollbars -> True]
```

[image]

Only problem I noticed so far is that when n gets large, Pane generates this outer frame saying very large output was generated. But I am sure there is a programmatic way (option somewhere) to turn that effect off, I just started looking at this and should be able to find a way around this once I have my coffee. (fingers crossed)

[image]

**good news**

The "Very large output was generated" ONLY showed up when in notebook interface. When I put the code in a Manipulate and and run it, it did not show this output frame. So, I am happy now and this issue is closed. I'll use Pane from now on. (Thanks again to Mike)

btw, to remove the message in question, here is a useful link I found:

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00935.html

but I did not need to do anything for what I am doing.

Comment: I've also noticed that `TableView` gets slow pretty rapidly as the data size grows. There are other solutions. Just put your data in a `Grid` and wrap `Pane` around it and use the `Scrollbars` option. I do this in dynamic interfaces all the time -- and the first time I started doing it was because `TableView` was so slow.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, thanks for the hint, I've overlooked pane with scrollbar options. Will try it later on my code to see how it will work. I think TableView is not yet ready for prime time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is a different enough method to post as another answer, though it clearly borrows from Mike's answer.

```
f = ToString @ 
    AccountingForm[#, {6, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}, 
     NumberPadding -> {"", ""}, SignPadding -> True] &;

data = {{-1234.8, 0.123}, {0.12345678, 0.1234}};

TableView[Map[f, data, {2}], ItemSize -> {{3, {8}}}, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> 11, Spacings -> {.2, .1}, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

---

Since using `ToString` was non-intuitive, I decided to explore it a bit more.  It seems that `TableView` suppresses quotation marks in strings, but only bare strings.  e.g.:

```
string = "\"\"\"test\"";

TableView[{{ string }}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TableView[{{ {string} }}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other interesting behavior can be seen with 2D formatted strings:

```
string = "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SqrtBox[\"5\"], \"2\"]\)";

TableView[{{ string }}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TableView[{{ {string} }}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Amazing. I have thought all the time the data feed to TableView has to be numeric. But Making it String worked! I guess that is why you are called Mr Wizard :)

Comment: @Nasser In fact it is my tribute to [Don Herbert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Herbert) but I'll accept the compliment.  `TableView` isn't documented in v7, so it's a guessing game.

Comment: That's for posting the additional stuff. Strange behaviour. This is not a "proper" function yet of course so maybe these kinds of things will when it is an official function.

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion:

Firstly make each element in your data into `AccountingForm`, or whatever Form you want:

```
f = AccountingForm[#, {6, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}, 
   NumberPadding -> {"", ""}, SignPadding -> True] &

newdata = {f[#[[1]]], f[#[[2]]]} & /@ data
```

Note that I've had a bit of a brain fade doing this. I'm sure there is an easier way than Mapping (Edit: the brain fade made me forget levelspec). This will give you output like this:

[image]

The problem of course is that you now have string characters showing and "conventional" attempts to switch this off failed ("conventional" == options inspector, `Style[]` etc.). But you can fix this by modifying two styles that exist in the Core.nb stylesheet. So you will need to edit the private styles in your current notebook -- and also remove `DefaultBaseStyle` from your code because it will cause conflicts with the stylesheet style. So **Format > Edit Stylesheet** and add this style:

```
Cell[StyleData["TableViewItemExpression"],
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 TemplateBoxOptions->{DisplayFunction->(StyleBox[#, Deployed -> False]& )}]
```

Actually that is really all you need to do but if you subsequently wanted to do some additional styling of the numbers then you need to modify a different style. Here is an example making the numbers red:

```
Cell[StyleData["TableViewGrid"],
 ContextMenu->FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "TableView"],
 ShowAutoStyles->False,
 AutoSpacing->False,
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 AutoNumberFormatting->True,
 LineIndent->0,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: +1, Mike, I do not know how to use your solution! I tried to use your cell command, but not sure how to use it. Could you please see my edit, with a small complete example, and see if you can put use it to add your final Cell command to it? something I can copy and paste and run on my end? Please note this is code that will run in a Manipulate demo. Hence I am not sure there is access to a Cell as in a normal notebook session. Thanks

Comment: I've edited and tried to be a bit more descriptive. This works by modifying your stylesheet. It is not a programmable solution so may not be the best answer but it is the only solution I know. Others may have better solutions ...i.e. programmatic ones. Thanks for using Map. I'd forgotten *levelspec*!

Comment: No problem Mike, thanks for your time and trying. Yes, I need a 'programmatic' solution since this will be used in a Manipulate demo. I do not know anything about changing style sheets and cells and such. I try to stay away from such low level stuff :)

Comment: Mike, is there a reason to not simply use `f = ToString @ AccountingForm[ . . .` and forego the style sheet stuff?

Comment: @MrWizard No reason other than I didn't think of it! I saw the string characters showing in the `TableView` so was not thinking in terms of making strings. Also I'd previously used stylesheeting to tailor `TableView` appearances before so that was what came to mind. Your answer is much simpler.

Comment: Me too, same thing. When I saw "" around the data in TableView when I passed it NumberForm wrapped data, I assumed it does not like Strings and needs numeric data. So making the data a string never entered as an option in my plan of attack.